# Изменение TextArea по событию input/change

Tags: javascript, html

мне нужно после любого изменения в TextArea делать вывод в консоль. В гугле искал, ничего подобного нет, хотя очень странно. Может решение проблемы невозможно? Буду благодарен!

```
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот первое попавшееся простое решение, которое точно есть в гугле:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
  console.log(textarea.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
```

Вам нужно что-то другое?